# Changing div visibility with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I want to use a link to toggle the visibility of a div element. The link has class `abstractShow` initially, so I'm trying to use the following code to toggle. However, it only works for the first click (by showing the div) and the click event for `abstractHide` is never triggered on subsequent clicks.

```
  $("a.abstractShow").click(function(){
      $(this).html('Hide')
      $(this).addClass("abstractHide");
      $(this).removeClass("abstractShow");
      $(this).next("div.abstract").show("fast");
  });
  $("a.abstractHide").click(function(){
      $(this).html('Show')
      $(this).addClass("abstractShow");
      $(this).removeClass("abstractHide");
      $(this).next("div.abstract").hide("fast");
  });
```

Comment: Instead of ID use class to identify the anchor tag in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding events with event handlers you use a selector, like `$("a.abstractHide")`. This looks in the current HTML for any elements matching that selector at ***the time of binding***. So when changing the class later, the event is not magically bound to that element, as it did'nt have that class when you initially bound the event.

Event delegation with on() is one option, another is to just use `toggle()`;

```
$("a.abstractShow").on('click', function(){
    var state = $(this).hasClass('active');
    $(this).html(state ? 'Hide' : 'Show')
           .toggleClass('active')
           .next("div.abstract").toggle(state);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

use this,

```
$("a.abstractHide").on('click', function(){
      $(this).text('Show')
      $(this).addClass("abstractShow");
      $(this).removeClass("abstractHide");
      $(this).next("div.abstract").hide("fast");
});
$("a.abstractHide").on('click', function(){
      $(this).text('Show')
      $(this).addClass("abstractShow");
      $(this).removeClass("abstractHide");
      $(this).next("div.abstract").hide("fast");
});
```

Comment: Rather use `.on()`, `.live()` is long time deprecated

Answer (score 0):

This is all you need:
<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/ayubib/4/edit)**</kbd>

```
$("a.abstractShow").click(function( e ){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).text( $(this).text()=='Show'?'Hide':'Show' )
           .next(".abstract").toggle(400);
});
```